# How do you remove values from a data frame based on whether they are present in another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames, the 1st contains a list of values I am looking to work with and the second contains these values plus a large number of other values. I am looking for the best way to remove the values that do not appear in the 1st data frame from the 2nddata frame to reduce the number of entries I am working with.

Example

**Input**

DF1

| Alpha | code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| D | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| F | 4 |

DF2

| Alpha | code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 23 |
| B | 12 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 32 |
| E | 23 |
| F | 45 |
| G | 51 |
| H | 26 |

Desired Output:

DF1

| Alpha | code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| D | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| F | 4 |

DF2

| Alpha | code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 23 |
| D | 32 |
| E | 23 |
| F | 45 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your first column in DF1 is called "Alpha", you can do this:

```
my_list_DF1 = DF1['Alpha'].unique().tolist() # gets all unique values of first column from DF1 into a list
```

Then, you can `filter` your DF2, to include only those values, using `isin`:

```
new_DF2 = DF2[DF2['Alpha'].isin(my_list_DF1)]
```

Which will result in a smaller DF2, only including the common values from the so called 'Alpha' column.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an inner join, dropping all rows that doesn't have an entry and merging all others:

```
pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on='Alpha', how='inner')
```

But then you would subsequently have to drop the columns you dont need, and posibly rename if some share a name.